# Indent like first line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, indentation

How can I indent a file such as its first line?

**Example:**

A file containing

```
     x=1+2+3+4+
5+6+7+8
+9+10+12
```

should be converted to

```
     x=1+2+3+4+
     5+6+7+8
     +9+10+12
```

I need this inside a shell-script on a Linux system. One-liners are preferred.

Comment: does the first line always start with `x=`?

Comment: @foampile no, just an example

Comment: are you limited to shell or can you use a scripting language?

Comment: @foampile I can use any common script language. Speed is less important.

Comment: i was gonna suggest `Perl`.  @Birei below posted a good answer.  albeit i am increasingly liking `awk` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 'if ($. == 1) { m/^(\s*)/; $space = $1 || q{}; next } s/^\s*/$space/' infile
```

It yields:

```
    x=1+2+3+4+
    5+6+7+8
    +9+10+12
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a,/[^ \t]/)}{sub(/^[ \t]*/,a[1]);print}' file.in
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -e '1{h;s/[^[:blank:]].*//;x;b' -e '}' -e 'G;s/[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```